# Plotting contour line over heatmap

Tags: heatmap, contour

I'm trying to combine a contour plot with a heatmap using Python, but I don't think the result is correct. The contour lines are generated, but they don't correspond to the heatmap. Is there anything we could do to resolve the problem?

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 14
array = [[-52.52,-55.121,-56.848,-57.222,-57.321,-59.453,-60.453,-62.244,-57.108,-59.453,-61,-57.656,-56.564,-53,-53.203,-56,-55,-59,-62,-68.546,-67,-62,-56.283,-57.805,-53.351,-52.924,-53], 
        [-49.865,-53.513,-54.56,-57.102,-58.046,-58.665,-59.65,-57.191,-62.953,-61,-59.426,-58.394,-54.932,-52.758,-51,-52,-55,-60,-68.277,-69.278,-69.127,-60.671,-58.383,-53.958,-52.997,-52.99,-53.88], 
        [-50.475,-57.495,-55.228,-58.517,-59.055,-58.5,-58.3,-54.457,-61.621,-61.648,-59.852,-58.74,-57.341,-52.468,-52.723,-53,-58,-60.797,-65.146,-71.035,-68.557,-67.19,-57.471,-57.096,-53.113,-53.833,-54], 
        [-50.642,-52.394,-54.926,-53.869,-45,-53,-48.345,-54,-57.976,-56,-57.409,-60.053,-57.815,-57.709,-55.903,-60.856,-59,-58,-68.923,-70.957,-70.555,-65.241,-55.072,-54.003,-52.989,-52.813,-54], 
        [-50.148,-51,-51,-49,-49.5,-50,-48.5,-53,-56,-58,-60.5,-60,-58,-59,-59,-61.5,-60,-40,-62,-65,-64,-65,-66,-65.5,-65,-64.5,-60], 
        [-49.446,-51.573,-51.864,-49.577,-47,-48.076,-46.166,-49.786,-56.066,-58,-59.532,-58.691,-57.686,-57.66,-54.365,-57,-58,-42,-44,-58.51,-66.304,-71.582,-61.59,-58.304,-60.941,-60,-59], 
        [-50.923,-51.346,-51.231,-50,-43,-46,-49,-46.987,-40,-42.902,-48.35,-59.142,-57.495,-70,-55.47,-52.934,-54.833,-48.755,-56,-59,-61.487,-64,-62.958,-58.653,-58.964,-60.686,-60],
        [-48.421,-52.575,-53.755,-52,-43,-39,-45.309,-38.89,-35.479,-33.864,-47.051,-50,-52,-54,-52,-53.74,-52.324,-52,-57,-56,-59.652,-62.436,-61.271,-56.855,-56.065,-59,-59.5], 
        [-52.861,-53.22,-52.654,-49,-46,-46.382,-45,-42.203,-37.837,-40,-31.976,-48,-52,-54,-66,-53,-53,-48,-59,-59,-59.64,-60.404,-61.468,-61.616,-55.102,-57.806,-58.22], 
        [-51.907,-49,-52.731,-46.822,-39,-43,-44.998,-47.376,-33,-36.521,-37.551,-44.29,-54,-55.67,-59,-54,-56,-49,-53,-57,-58.674,-60.732,-61.603,-61.068,-61.763,-58.45,-59.45], 
        [-49.78,-51.25,-48.75,-44,-39,-47,-46.25,-46,-45.25,-46,-47.2,-50,-52,-57,-60.5,-55,-54,-54,-52,-56,-55,-62.5,-64.5,-63,-62,-62.5,-62], 
        [-50.372,-47,-41.392,-41,-40,-46.933,-48.527,-45,-45.016,-46.311,-40.575,-38.672,-57,-58.232,-57.27,-61,-55,-56,-57,-51,-59.173,-58.949,-59.532,-60.225,-62.219,-61.663,-62], 
        [-47.082,-41,-37,-38,-44,-46,-40,-41.963,-46.997,-47.67,-43,-44,-50,-54,-58.323,-59.182,-57,-56,-55,-53,-60,-61.353,-58.351,-59.714,-58.773,-56.595,-57], 
        [-49.54,-44,-41,-44,-36,-42,-43.486,-42.432,-44.102,-39.096,-47.164,-47,-58,-50,-52.327,-56,-51,-56,-61,-53,-53,-60,-56,-57,-58,-56.949,-57], 
        [-49.87,-43.268,-42.207,-41,-44,-45,-38.718,-34.296,-34.841,-37.424,-33.914,-50,-54,-42,-53,-58.228,-54,-56,-60,-56,-58,-59.147,-57,-53.668,-54,-54.361,-55],
        [-54.859,-51.864,-57.225,-42,-47,-45.054,-34.565,-36.678,-35.399,-27.215,-42.495,-42,-52.499,-48,-45.717,-59.343,-54,-54,-59,-59,-59,-57,-56,-57.373,-55.407,-53.927,-54], 
        [-57.392,-62.547,-65.162,-41.532,-40,-40,-29.564,-31.388,-27.217,-31.549,-43.564,-42.55,-49.813,-50.753,-45.775,-58.063,-58.213,-57,-58,-61,-54.876,-58.436,-61.86,-59.256,-55.225,-54.662,-53], 
        [-58.421,-55.428,-62,-57.942,-52,-42.066,-30.343,-29.5,-26.297,-43.92,-49.577,-48.421,-44.249,-52,-53.654,-56.78,-60.276,-58,-56,-58,-53,-53.362,-63.076,-61.127,-54.457,-55.967,-55], 
        [-57.305,-56.927,-64.199,-49.451,-53.785,-43,-29.304,-31.816,-31.894,-46.703,-47.62,-49,-50,-56,-57,-57.107,-60.403,-60,-52,-56,-58.475,-53.067,-62.994,-62.859,-55.034,-53.658,-54], 
        [-53.495,-62.5,-63.384,-48,-50,-44.788,-30.892,-39.91,-38.98,-49.859,-41.845,-46.97,-53.742,-55.424,-55,-55.466,-58,-59.794,-54,-53.031,-57.404,-53.388,-53.74,-53.061,-52.962,-53.676,-54], 
        [-53.109,-60,-53.452,-53.279,-50,-50.768,-45.344,-41.21,-50.578,-50.989,-52.6,-55.043,-55.33,-53.133,-54.662,-55,-53.8,-54.195,-57.218,-55.942,-55.443,-54.885,-53.68,-53.209,-52.945,-53.542,-54.5],
        [-53.974,-54,-55.169,-53.528,-51.789,-49.705,-50.123,-49.419,-49.102,-52.371,-53.007,-55.338,-53.139,-53.11,-53.041,-54.011,-54,-54.341,-55.546,-55.27,-55.046,-53.779,-53.23,-52.991,-52.98,-52.955,-53]]


labels = [0.45, 0.90, 1.35, 1.80, 2.25, 2.70, 3.15, 3.60, 4.05, 4.50, 4.95, 5.40, 5.85, 6.30, 6.75, 7.2, 7.65, 8.1, 8.55, 9.00, 9.45, 10.00]
columns = [0.45, 0.90, 1.35, 1.80, 2.25, 2.70, 3.15, 3.60, 4.05, 4.50, 4.95, 5.40, 5.85, 6.30, 6.75, 7.2, 7.65, 8.1, 8.55, 9.00, 9.45, 9.90, 10.35, 10.8, 11.25, 11.7, 12]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = labels, columns=columns)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
sn.heatmap(df_cm, cmap="jet", cbar=True, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(0.45, 22.0)
plt.title('AP1')
```

clip_on=False)

```
data = gaussian_filter(np.random.randn(20, 40), sigma=2)

ax.contour(np.arange(.5, data.shape[1]), np.arange(.5, data.shape[0]), data, colors='red')
plt.xlabel('x(m)', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y(m)', fontsize=16)
plt.savefig('heatmap_s5.png')
plt.savefig('heatmap_s5.pdf')
```

[image]